# How to redirect all directory but one (htaccess)

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I tried to redirect the entire subdomain content to another domain but leave wp-admin folder of that subdomain stay.

**REDIRECT sub.example.com TO example.org BUT NOT sub.example.com/wp-admin**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com/(?!wp-admin) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.org [L,R=301]
```

that won't work

Comment: I think the [NC] should be [C] only, because N would make apache reevaluate the statement with the match, which is missing in the second try.

Comment: Thanks, but it gets me 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I haven't used apache some time and cannot try it out, but as far as I remember apache rewrites often are multi line. Maybe you can define an exclude rule by prepending something like: `RewriteRule ^/wp-admin - [L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant match against uri in `%{HTTP_HOST}` condition, you need to match against uri in `RewriteRule` directive

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!wp-admin).*)$ http://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```